# How to create a fixed footer - jquerymobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Any one help me. Thanks in advance. I want to move the controls based on the browser resolution? How to do it?[image]

Comment: I know stackoverflow is comfortable, but you could find an hourto browse some jquery mobile documentation [or just read the main menu http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a2/ ] once and you will know where to look for answers instead of waiting for someone to post a link here on stackoverflow.

Comment: Hi Naughter, Thanks. I already checked with those URL. If I used "data-position:fixed" then it shows the screen and also it is not static. I want to display the footer in the static format. [(I dont want to movable footer object with in the screen)]

Comment: you mean data-position="fixed" ? There are three ways a footer can be set up. Its all in docs there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do it you have to read the following page of jQuery Mobile documentation:

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a2/#docs/toolbars/bars-fixed.html

PS. Other pages in docs present other interesting things you can do with footers and headers.
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a2/#docs/toolbars/index.html